# Android Bluetooth Discoverbility Dialog

Tags: android, bluetooth, dialog, visibility

when I want to connect a Bluetooth device I have to turn on the visibility of my device.
Is there a possibility to prevent the dialog which asks for permission to start visibility for a given time?
It should only start and not ask for permission.

Thanks for your help;)

Answer (score 0):

Its a security mechanism of android. You cant remove it. But you can pair your devices, this causes that the dialogue isnt shown anymore.

Comment: Is it possible to pair with a device without the pairing dialog, when I know the Mac-address of the device. Maybe to create my own BluetoothDevice form Mac and then create the bond?